# Python - Small paginator

Tags: python

Let's say I have a max_number defined by sistem.

For example: 423

I need, in this case, 5 list:

I'll use the 2 items in the list has my from - to indicators to make a subset of a db table.

from - to:

```
[1,100]
[101,200]
[201,300]
[301,400]
[401,423]
```

What would be the quickest approach of doing this?

I have this function but it's still buggy:

```
def paginator(desde,cantidad_maxima):
    lst = []
    if(cantidad_maxima < 100):
        lst.append(desde)
        lst.append(cantidad_maxima)
        print(lst)
    hasta = 100

    lst.append(desde)
    lst.append(hasta)

    print('Primera vuelta del paginador:')
    print(lst)

    while hasta < cantidad_maxima:
        desde = desde + 100
        hasta = hasta + 100 + (cantidad_maxima%100)

        lst.append(desde)
        lst.append(hasta)

        print('Desde - Hasta:')
        print(lst)

paginator(1, 423) # returns [1, 100, 101, 223, 201, 346, 301, 469]
```

Comment: Nice, Thomas. But it returns: [[0, 99], [100, 199], [200, 299], [300, 399], [400, 499]], and it should be: [[0, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300], [301, 400], [401, 423]]

Comment: Sorry, there was a small mistake and I got interrupted -- here the corrected version: `[[i,i+99 if i+99 < 423 else 423] for i in range(0,424,100)]`

Comment: works, great. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one-line list comprehension:

```
max = 423
intervals = [[x*100+1,x*100+100] for x in range(0,max//100)]+([[100*(max//100)+1,max]] if max%100 else [])
intervals
>>> [[1, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300], [301, 400], [401, 423]]
```

This is built up from the following components:

1. `range(0,max//100)` yields a list `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
2. Each of these items gets added as `[x * 100, x * 100+100]` to result in `[[0, 100], [100, 200], [200, 300], [300, 400]]`
3. The first value in each pair needs incrementing by `1`. The `+1` takes care of that.
4. This leads to a list of whole hundreds only, so the remainder must be added: `.. +([[100*(max//100)+1, max]]`, which is a short list `[401, 423]`.
5. (icing on the cake) ... *except* when `max` is a round hundreds number, of course. In that case, `if` expects an `else` and so I add an empty list `[]`, which does not contribute anything to the result.

   a. ... and it needs a further `if` in case this last segment is the only one.

Some more results (list comprehension left out for clarity):

```
max = 96
>>> [[1, 96]]

max = 100
>>> [[1, 100]]

max = 101
>>> [[1, 100], [101, 101]]
```

Comment: Just a small correction, the requirements are that is should start with [1,100] [101,200] and so on.. ty.

Comment: @OmarGonzales: you may want to change that in your question, then.

Comment: You're right. But both options are great to have. thank you for your time.

Comment: @OmarGonzales: you're welcome! I changed the code, it needed just taking out the exception case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple list comprehension to achieve what you want.

**EDIT**: After the OP updated the question, the requirements have changed a bit. Here now the updated solution:

```
upper = 423
stride = 100

intervals = [[i,i+stride-1 if i+stride-1 < upper else upper] for i in range(1,upper+1,stride)]

print(intervals)
```

this gives:

```
[[1, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300], [301, 400], [401, 423]]
```

Comment: This is what I needed: `[[i,i+99 if i+99 < cantidad_maxima else cantidad_maxima] for i in range(0,cantidad_maxima + 1,100)]`. TY.

Comment: @OmarGonzales The first version of the answer is basically the same as what I wrote in the comment, just more easily generalised.